# When I use Web SQL,I am in trouble

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to insert some data into web sql database.But I met a problem.

My code :

```
database();

for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){ 
  showid = m[i].id;
  showtitle = m[i].title;
  insert();
} 

function database(){
  //open the database 
  db = window.openDatabase("youyanchu", "1.0","youyanchu",500000);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
   var table = tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE showList (id int PRIMARY KEY, title NVARCHAR, finishDate NVARCHAR, status NVARCHAR, tkCount NVARCHAR )");
  });
}

//INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY

function insert(){
  db.transaction(function(ar) {
  ar.executeSql("INSERT INTO showList (id, title,finishDate,status) values(?,?,?,?)", [showid,showtitle,'aaa','bbb']);
  });
}
```

m.length is 3 and "m" should be

aaa = {'id':'999','title':'ninini'}

bbb = {'id':'888','title':'ninini'}

ccc = {'id':'777','title':'ninini'}

At last,just "ccc" display in the web sql.

How to insert all data into the database?What mistake I made in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Since `tx.executeSql` is asynchronous, I believe your `loop` finishes before the first `insert` runs.

Hence `showid` and `showtitle` will always have the last values of the object `m`

**Try this instead:**

```
for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){ 
    insert(m[i].id, m[i].title);
} 


function insert(id, title){

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    txexecuteSql("INSERT INTO showList (id, title,finishDate,status) values(?,?,?,?)", [id, title,'aaa','bbb']);
  });

}
```